# Chart.js ajax with multiple dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I've successfully managed to create a line chart by retrieving the dataset from an ajax call when the line chart only has a single line.
I now need to create a line chart with 2 lines, but I can't get it working.

My ajax return data is built in php. This is the code:

```php
$returnData['line'] = array(
  'type' => 'line',
  'title' => 'Title',
  'labels' => array('Jan','Feb'),
  'datasets' => array(
    array(
      'data' => array(0,50),
      'borderColor' => "#f7464a",
      'label' => "Label 1",
      'fill' => false
    ),
    array(
      'data' => array(10,20),
      'borderColor' => "#8e5ea2",
      'label' => "Label 2",
      'fill' => true
    )
  )
);
echo json_encode($returnData);
```

My jQuery ajax call is:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/chart_data",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(rtnData) {
        $.each(rtnData, function(dataType, data) {
            console.log(data.datasets);
            var ctx = document.getElementById("linechart").getContext("2d");
            var config = {
                type: data.type,
                data: {
                    datasets: [data.datasets],
                    labels: data.labels
                },
                options:  {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: data.title
                    }
                }
            };
            window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
        });
    },
    error: function(rtnData) {
        alert('error' + rtnData);
    }
});
```

The data looks good when I view what has been logged in the console, so I don't know why this isn't working.
All I get is the chart, but no lines.

I'm looking for a future-proofed solution where I can add as many lines as needed to the chart just by amending the php code, without then having to change the jQuery too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spotted my mistake in case anybody else runs into this....the square brackets need to be removed from the 'datasets' parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/chart_data",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(rtnData) {
        $.each(rtnData, function(dataType, data) {
                console.log(data.datasets);
            var ctx = document.getElementById("linechart").getContext("2d");
            var config = {
                type: data.type,
                data: {
                    datasets: data.datasets,
                    labels: data.labels
                },
                options:  {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: data.title
                    }
                }
            };
            window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
        });
    },
    error: function(rtnData) {
        alert('error' + rtnData);
    }
});
```